# Diagonalizable pro-algebraic group in Kottwitz's 1985 Compositio paper

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, langlands-conjectures, reductive-groups

In Kottwitz's 1985 Compositio paper,
[Isocrystals with additional structure](http://www.numdam.org/item/CM_1985__56_2_201_0), first page, paragraph 4:

> Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the diagonalizable pro-algebraic group over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with character group $\mathbb{Q}$

What is this $\mathbb{D}$?... I completely have no idea (and it is used repeatedly in the paper)... Where can I find a more detailed definition?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One just take the inverse limit of $\mathbb G_m$ under the inverse system of maps $\mathbb G_m \to \mathbb G_m$ by raising to a natural number power. Or, equivalently, the sequence $\dots \mathbb G_m \to \mathbb G_m \to \mathbb G_m \to \mathbb G_m$ where the $n$th-to-last map is raising to the $n$th power.

The character group of this is the forward limit of the character group of $\mathbb G_m$ along the dual maps. The character group of $\mathbb G_m$ is $\mathbb Z$, and we haver arranged things so the forward limit is $\mathbb Q$.

It is clearly diagonalizable, as it is an inverse limit of diagonlizable (i.e. commutative reductive, I guess) algebraic groups.

It is not too hard to check this is unique.

In general, for any discrete group, you can construct a diagonalizable pro-algebraic group with that character group, by taking an inverse limit over finitely generated subgroups.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I have not yet understood how this pro-alg gp is used in the paper, but your definition should help greatly! By the way, do you know where I can find expositions about pro-alg. gps (and the diagonalizable property)? I haven't succeeded with googling yet...